# Can windows 7 be used as a Compute Node in a Windows HPC system?

Tags: windows, windows-7, hpc

We have several systems with windows 7 installed on. Is there any chance to create a cluster with these systems without installing any windows server. I mean we want to use windows 7s as computing nodes in our cluster.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In HPC Pack 2012 you can install them as Workstation nodes if they're running Windows 7 Enterprise, Windows 7 Professional, or Windows 7 Ultimate

From https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff601843(v=ws.11).aspx